# Allow nginx to send strong etag after gzipping

Tags: node.js, nginx, server, etag, akamai

I have a node server that will send a huge payload, which I am currently gzipping at nginx layer. nginx is making the etag weak upon gzipping and akamai doesn't cache based on weak headers.
Need a way of by passing weak etag generation at nginx layer or some other solution to enable caching at CDN layer.
Tried doing gzip at node layer using [fastify-compress](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-compress) but the QPS value is decreasing drastically if this is done.
Can someone tell me if there is some good way of handling this situation?